# Dynamic multitenant JpaRepository in Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, multi-tenant, entitymanager, jparepository

We have 500+ databases (one per blockchain), all of which have the same schema and JPA Entities.

We have a multithreaded Spring Boot app which uses Hibernate.

We need the ability to choose, at runtime, which database to interact with (which depends on which blockchain a set of data relates to).

Is there a way to switch the underlying database a JpaRepository interacts with dynamically at runtime?  We need distributed transaction support since we have use cases where we must write to 2 databases in the same transaction.

Do we need to run the 2 database transactions in their own thread and the wrapper/parent transaction in another thread?  How will the EntityManagers work in a threadsafe manner knowing that a JpaRepository can write to 500+ databases but, in the current transaction, only writes to 1?

Any guidance you can offer is greatly appreciated.  I've tried multiple approaches and none seem to fit these requirements:

1. Java packages to scan is the same for all databases (same data model, same Entity objects, different databases)
2. Change the underlying DataSource dynamically at runtime (but be sure EntityManager still behaves correctly)
3. Coordinate transactions which write to multiple databases
4. Threadsafe EntityManager usage
5. DataSources are created dynamically, not in application.properties and not in a huge @Configuration file with a @Bean each (we load our 500+ configurations from a separate database and use DataSourceBuilder to create those)